# Python - Tkinter - paste png trasparent image mouse cordinate and resize

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

my goal is to create an image editor for image augumentation.
Basically what I'd like to do:

1. run main code and load background image into canvas
2. capture mouse click event for coordinates gathering on main canvas
3. paste previous loaded PNG trasparent image on background-canvas
4. possibility to resize with mouse pasted PNG transparent foreground image
5. save pasted image relative cordinates (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)

I've started with this code:

```
import PIL.Image as p
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    #setting up a tkinter canvas with scrollbars
    frame = Frame(root, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="C:/",title='Choose an image.')
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(File))
    logo=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("C:\\logo1.png"))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def printcoords(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console

        img.paste(logo, (event.x,event.y))
        print (event.x,event.y)
    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)

    root.mainloop()`enter code here`
```

I'm getting this error while trying to paste image on background at line:

```
img.paste(logo, (0,0))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Do you have any suggestion?
Many thanks

#### Update

Full traceback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\yolo\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/tensorflow1/Projects/xx/yolo_preproc/augumentation/yolo_trainer.py", line 46, in printcoords
    img.paste(logo, (0,0))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\yolo\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 165, in paste
    im.load()
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback?

Comment: updated with full traceback. thx

Answer (score 2):

You should know that in function`Img.paste(argument_A,[argument_B])`,

`argument_A` and `Img` should be a `PIL.Image` object.But In your code,

```
logo=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("C:\\logo1.png"))
```

`logo` is a `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` object.
So it will get error.

Now you should use `logo=PIL.Image.open("C:\\logo1.png")` instead of `logo=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("C:\\logo1.png"))`.

Comment: Edited this line, img.paste(logo.convert('RGBA'), (event.x,event.y)), paste action now works, but the PNG is not trasparent and not in the mouse click coordinates.

Comment: @user3925023 Is your PNG transparent from the beginning?I can load a PNG transparent image